# Gráfico de barras - Agrupamento manual dos dados

Tags: r, ggplot2, barplot

Bom dia pessoal. Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de barras com o ggplot(), mas estou com muita dificuldade em um detalhe.

Basicamente eu gostaria de agrupar manualmente os dados que ficam inseridos dentro de cada bin do meu histograma.

Gostaria que as barras ficassem representassem intervalos que eu determino. EX ao invés de aparecer o número 2, 4, 6 em baixo de uma barra, gostaria que aparecesse [2 a 4), [4 a 6), [6 a 8).
como na figura a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código até agora:

```
insira o código aqui
p8 <- ggplot(TGL_Filtered , aes(x = TP)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = 2.5,
             colour = barlines, fill = barfill) +
scale_x_continuous(name = "Tp (s)",
                 breaks = seq(0, 25, 5),
                 limits=c(0,25)) +
scale_y_continuous(name = "Porcentagem %") +
ggtitle("Período de Pico") +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d3d3d3",linetype = "dashed"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
    text=element_text(family="Tahoma"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 9),
    axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 9))

p8
```

Comment: Opa Rodrigo, pra podermos executar o seu código e podermos testar é interessante fornecer dados para reprodução. Veja algumas dicas de como fazer uma pergunta em R aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6701/115233.

Comment: Obrigado, não havia me atentado a este detalhes.
Muito interessante este guia.
Obrigado novamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `ggplot2` para você definir a categoria em que vão ser feitos os gráficos de barra você precisa fornecer uma variável categórica. Você pode criar essa variável categórica manualmente utilizando o comando `cut` e em seguida utilizá-la para criar o seu gráfico:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
diamonds$bins <- cut(diamonds$x, breaks = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
  aes(x = bins, weight = carat) +
  geom_bar(fill = '#fcbba1') +
  theme_bw()
```

o resultado obtido será o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]